# ADB install uninstalls my last adb installed apk

Tags: android, adb

I have 10 apps I'm developing and would like to have them all on my phone at the same time to show others. However every time I install one it 'uninstalls' the other. By 'uninstalls' I mean if I copy the link to my home screen the old app will not start, but adb install old-app.apk says already installed.

Is this normal? Or do I have some package naming conflict or something?

Comment: that is not by design at all, not sure what's up but I definitely have 2-3 apps I've written installed on emulator via adb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one application can be on the device for any given package. If you have 10 apps all with the same package, only one can be installed at any given time.